# Understanding the definition of the joint probability mass function?

Tags: probability

In my textbook it says the joint probability mass function of two discrete random variables is defined as:

$$P_{XY}(x,y) = P(X =x, Y=y) $$

What does the subscript $XY$ below the P mean and what does the little $x$ and $y$ mean in context of $P(X =x, Y=y) $?

If someone could give an example that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upper case letters denote variables. Lower case letters denote specific values for variables. This statement says the pmf is defined as the probability of an event that gives each variable specific values. In particular, these values are the pmf's arguments.